# How loop through HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom

This code makes it so when the user clicks one of the colors (color1-4) it sets the CSS `display` property of all the shoes `none` except for the color that was clicked, whose `display` is set to `block`. The code looks dirty and an employer would not approve.

How would I go about making that a for loop, or otherwise make the code cleaner?

```js
color2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    shoe.style.display = "none";
    shoe3.style.display = "none";
    shoe5.style.display = "none";
    shoe2.style.display = "block";
    console.log('u removed it and added another');
});

color3.addEventListener('click', () => {
    shoe.style.display = "none";
    shoe3.style.display = "none";
    shoe5.style.display = "none";
    shoe2.style.display = "none";
    shoe3.style.display = "block";
    console.log('u removed it and added another');
});

color4.addEventListener('click', () => {
    shoe.style.display = "none";
    shoe3.style.display = "none";
    shoe5.style.display = "none";
    shoe3.style.display = "none";
    shoe5.style.display = "block";
    console.log('u removed it and added another');
});

color1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    shoe.style.display = "block";
    shoe2.style.display = "none";
    shoe3.style.display = "none";
    shoe4.style.display = "none";
    shoe5.style.display = "none";
    console.log('u removed it and added another');
});

color2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    shoe.style.display = "none";
    shoe3.style.display = "none";
    shoe5.style.display = "none";
    shoe2.style.display = "block";
    console.log('u removed it and added another');
});
```

Comment: You'll need to use arrays. Check out https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: color1, color2 ... are html elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of Array and a custom function to manipulate DOM elements, here is an basic example:

```
var shoes = [s1,s2,s3]; //DOM element arrays
colorShoe = (shoe) =>{
  for(let i=0; i<shoes.length;i++){
    if(shoes[i] === shoe){
      //Handling style
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this and see if you can modify your code like the below:

```
const colorList = [color1, color2, color3]; // you can add more
const shoeList = [shoe1, shoe2, shoe3]; // you can add more
[color1, color2, color3].forEach((color, colorIndex) => {
  color.addEventListener('click', () => {
    shoeList.forEach((shoe, shoeIndex) => {
      if (colorIndex === shoeIndex) {
        shoe.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        shoe.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this if you dun wan to use array . Just use window['var name'+the index number] then you can add the thing you wan to do on the back :D thank you : D

```
color3.addEventListener('click', () => {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            if (i == 3) shoe.style.display = "block";
            else {
                window['shoe'+i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        console.log('u removed it and added another');
    });

    color4.addEventListener('click', () => {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            if (i == 4) shoe.style.display = "block";
            else {
                window['shoe'+i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        console.log('u removed it and added another');
    });

    color1.addEventListener('click', () => {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            if (i == 1) shoe.style.display = "block";
            else {
                window['shoe'+i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        console.log('u removed it and added another');
    });
```